# Installing Redmine Plugins Gives me Long Error List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, rake, redmine

I am having trouble installing plugins in Redmine 3.1.0-stable. I have placed the plugins in the plugin directory and restarted my server using:

```
bundle exec ruby bin/rails server -b 162.209.99.106 webrick -e production
```

I have also tried to use the command rake redmine:plugins:migrate which gives me this. I see that is says Access denied for user root@localhost but that doesn't make sense as that isn't what is configured in my config/databases.yml? Any advice?

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:230:in `table_exists?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:97:in `get_primary_key'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:85:in `reset_primary_key'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:73:in `primary_key'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/attribute_assignment.rb:15:in `attributes_protected_by_default'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:337:in `block in protected_attributes_configs'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:222:in `yield'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:222:in `protected_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:126:in `block in attr_protected'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:125:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:125:in `attr_protected'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/app/models/custom_field.rb:32:in `<class:CustomField>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/app/models/custom_field.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine/field_format.rb:83:in `field_attributes'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine/field_format.rb:86:in `<class:Base>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine/field_format.rb:48:in `<module:FieldFormat>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine/field_format.rb:19:in `<module:Redmine>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine/field_format.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:443:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:plugins:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

HERE IS THE COMMAND RUN WITH --TRACE flag ( Looks the same to me)

```
** Invoke redmine:plugins:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:230:in `table_exists?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:97:in `get_primary_key'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:85:in `reset_primary_key'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:73:in `primary_key'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/attribute_assignment.rb:15:in `attributes_protected_by_default'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:337:in `block in protected_attributes_configs'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:222:in `yield'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:222:in `protected_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:126:in `block in attr_protected'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:125:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:125:in `attr_protected'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/app/models/custom_field.rb:32:in `<class:CustomField>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/app/models/custom_field.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine/field_format.rb:83:in `field_attributes'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine/field_format.rb:86:in `<class:Base>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine/field_format.rb:48:in `<module:FieldFormat>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine/field_format.rb:19:in `<module:Redmine>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine/field_format.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/lib/redmine.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0.1/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:443:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:217:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:215:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:215:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:plugins:migrate => environment
```

HERE IS THE ERROR --------

```
 # production: adapter: mysql2 database: redmine host: localhost username: 
 redmine password: "***********" encoding: utf8 development: adapter: mysql2 
 database: redmine_dev host: localhost username: redmine-dev password: 
 "***********" encoding: utf8 
 # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and 
 # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake". 
 # Do not set this db to the same as development or production. test: adapter: 
 mysql2 database: redmine_test host: localhost username: redmine_test 
 password: 
 "************" encoding: utf8 

 # PostgreSQL configuration example 
 #production: # adapter: postgresql 
 # database: redmine 
 # host: localhost 
 # username: postgres 
 # password: "postgres" 

 # SQLite3 configuration example 
 #production: 
 # adapter: sqlite3 
 # database: db/redmine.sqlite3 
 # SQL Server configuration example #production: 
 # adapter: sqlserver 
 # database: redmine 
 # host: localhost 
 # username: jenkins 
 # password: jenkins
```

Comment: What have you configured in config/database.yml? It sounds like that may be the culprit so seeing that file may help us answer your question.

Comment: I just configured the Production Variables firsts, then i tried with the development and test Commented out, then I created seperate databases for Production, Development and Test I'm still gettin the error Here are the Contents of the file:

Comment: production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: redmine
  password: "***********"
  encoding: utf8

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine_dev
  host: localhost
  username: redmine-dev
  password: "***********"
  encoding: utf8

Comment: # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine_test
  host: localhost
  username: redmine_test
  password: "************"
  encoding: utf8

Comment: # PostgreSQL configuration example
#production:
#  adapter: postgresql
#  database: redmine
#  host: localhost
#  username: postgres
#  password: "postgres"
# SQLite3 configuration example
#production:
#  adapter: sqlite3
#  database: db/redmine.sqlite3

# SQL Server configuration example
#production:
#  adapter: sqlserver
#  database: redmine
#  host: localhost
#  username: jenkins
#  password: jenkins

Comment: Sorry for splitting up the file like that it was only allowing me 600 characters... Thank doe the Quick Reply I really need to get this working ASAP!

Comment: Can you add it to the question so it's nicely formatted?